# pyqt Qlabel drag and drop functionality will be forbided when used dll func

Tags: python, dll, pyqt5

I developed a drop func in Qlabel(pyqt),Usually it works fine。
but i will be forbided when i used a method in a dll,it will show a red ban cursor。

python version：3.8.5
Any idea about that? thank you

```
class Droplabel(QtWidgets.QLabel):
    def __init__(self, parent, father):
        super(Droplabel, self).__init__(parent)
        self.parent = father
        self.suffx = ["png", "jpg", "jpeg", "bmp", "tga"]
        self.setAcceptDrops(True)
        self.pixpath = ""
        self.setScaledContents(False)
        self.setPixmap(QPixmap(""))

    def dragEnterEvent(self, a0: QtGui.QDragEnterEvent) -> None:
        a0.accept()

    def dropEvent(self, a0: QtGui.QDropEvent) -> None:
        self.pixpath = a0.mimeData().text()
        self.pixpath = self.pixpath.replace("file:///", "")
        if self.pixpath.split(".")[-1] in self.suffx:
            # 触发更新事件
            self.parent.set_current_ima(self.pixpath)
```

Comment: Please explain what you mean by "a method in a dll".

Comment: sorry,I am not good at the english，i use c++ compiled a dll, i use python calling functions from the DLL file

Comment: Then please try to find somebody that could help you in writing a question that can be *understood*. Also, clarify what that DLL has to do with the question and its code, as it's impossible to understand the problem right now.